# WPF create a button for each view, which will set it as the content of a ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF, MVVM program whose MainWindow is separated into a `ListBox` sidebar and a main part with a `ContentControl`. I want to create a functionality that will populate the ListBox with a button for each view that I have in my project and set its command such that clicking it will set the content of the ContentControl to the associated view **automatically**, i.e. so that I don't have to manually enter code when adding a new view. Something like iterate through all *view* files or something like that.

EDIT:
Perhaps I'm AGAIN not clear enough.

What I have and can do - type like a monkey "new Button, yadda yadda" every time I add a new view to my project.

What I want - write a piece of black magic that goes something like "There are 6 views in this project, I'll just make 6 buttons each such that, when clicked, will navigate to the appropriate view, without the guy who wrote me having to write any additional line of code any time a new view is added".

How can I achieve that and is it such a good idea, to begin with?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For instructional purposes, I'll be calling your "view" class `View`.

1. Create some sort of collection object (`List<View>`, `ObservableCollection<View>`, etc.) to store all of the `View`s.
2. Assign this collection to a dependency property. I'll call it `Views`.
3. Declare a dependency property for the selected/active view. I'll call it `SelectedView`.
4. Bind `ListBox.ItemsSource` to `Views`.
5. Bind `ListBox.SelectedItem` to `View`.
6. Bind `ContentControl.Content` to `View` as well.

With the above setup, the `ContentControl` will display whatever `View` is selected in the `ListBox`.

Comment: any idea how to iterate all `View` files in my project?

Comment: @Shrodinger Are the views code files, or some kidn of data file?

Comment: They are .cs files.

Comment: @Shrodinger If each one is its own class, the easiest thing would be to just manually define some `static` list contaiing an instsance of each of the view classes.